# Nunit Mocking is little bit of confusing

Tags: c#, mocking, nunit

How to mock the query, I want to test this in Nunit. Can someone help me with snippet?this is the exact Service.cs, I need to mockup and do an Nunit on the same.

```
internal class Sample : ISsample
{
  public sample( IRepository<ProductVariant> productVariantRepository, IRepository<Product> productRepository)
    {

        _productVariantRepository = productVariantRepository;
        _productRepository = productRepository;
    }
   public string getValueabc(int a, int b)
   {
            vvar productVariantId =
                (from pv in _productVariantRepository.Table
                 join p in _productRepository.Table on pv.ProductId equals p.Id
                 where !p.Deleted && !pv.Deleted && p.Id == sku
                 orderby pv.Published descending
                 select pv.Id).FirstOrDefault();

            if (productVariantId == 0)
            {
                throw new ErrorCodeException(CatalogErrorCode.ProductVariantNotFound);
            }
           return "Hi";
     }
 }
```

Comment: What are your `_VariantRepository` and `_productRepository`? If they are repository interfaces, you can mock them.

Comment: hi @Arghya C, yes its an interface repository,updating the code